# How to populate a new window before opening it?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I write code like this -

```
chatWindow = window.open("chatWindow.html", "Chat Window",
 resizable=0,width=700,height=600);

var currentUserElement = chatWindow.document.createElement("currentUserElement");
    currentUserElement.setAttribute("id", "currentUserElement");
    currentUserElement.setAttribute("value",currentUserName);
```

However, is there a way I can do the createElement() part first before the call to window.open()?

Comment: Have the server create it in the first place. :)

Answer (score 3):

The only way I see how you can do it on the client only is using a blob.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="textId"></input>
<button id="buttonId">Open new Window</button>
```

And the JS:

```
var button = $("#buttonId");

button.click(function () {
  var text = $("#textId").val();
  var html = "<html>"
      html += "<head><title>Window: " + text + "</title></head>";
      html += "<body onLoad='javascript:alert(\"" + text + "\")'>";
      html += text
      html += "</body></html>";
  var blob = new Blob([html], {type: 'text/html'});
  window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
});​
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67tKR/2/) to illustrate that approach. As you can see the JS will be also be executed. There is an interesting [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/streaming/screenshare/) about screensharing on html5rocks that utilizes this technique.